# React : Pagination is not Working Smoothly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, loopback, semantic-ui-react

I am working on pagination in React . I am fetching data from online server through API . API was built in Loopback . I have some problem regarding `next` and `previous` button . I make logic for pagination if user want to render next page data it will click on next , If User want to load previous page data it click on previous button . With my logic Next button is working fine , it rendering the next page data if user click on next button but problem is that if user want to click on `previous` button it loading next page data not like previous page data. Somebody please help me how I can make this type of pagination if user click on next it must load next page data or user want to load previous page data it must load previous page with `prev` button .

**Code**

```
        class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:3001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have just write btnClick(e) in one way that adding the skip:skip+10 but if you need previous data it should subtract skip:skip-10

So the solution is

```
btnClick(e,type){
const Item=this.state.Item;
const skip=this.state.skip;
If(type === “next”){
this.setState({
  Item,
  skip:skip-10
},()=> this.getData())
} else {
  this.setState({
  Item,
  skip:skip+10
 })
}
```

}

// call function this.btnClick(e, “next”)
Or prev for pervious

Comment: Thank You for your comment but sorry It not working .. I provided full code in Question can you please edit it with your own code if it work . Thanks

Comment: semantic-ui-react does not have any callback for next and prev so i think that wouldn't be possible still one thing you can try instead overwriting state.data push the new reponse data to state.data in this way it will have the previous data and will work fine but you need avoid pagination onClick parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for the Pagination component at https://react.semantic-ui.com/addons/pagination/ , You will see that you are passing `this.btnClick` into `onClick={this.btnClick}` when it should be passed into `onPageChange={this.btnClick}`

```js
<Pagination
    boundaryRange={0}
    onPageChange={this.btnClick}
    defaultActivePage={1}
    ellipsisItem={null}
    firstItem={null}
    lastItem={null}
    siblingRange={1}
    totalPages={10}
/>
```

The parameters that are passed into onPageChange are as such:
`onPageChange(event: SyntheticEvent, data: object)`

It is not clear the difference between Item and Skip in state and what you are trying to accomplish with your `btnClick` function. It does not look like you are accounting for the possibility that you could click a numbered page on the pagination component instead of just the `nextPage` and PrevPage` buttons.

I'm going to assume `Item` indicates the current page you want to be on, in which case inside your btnClick function, you can grab the next active page from the `data` parameter (this will return the paginated number of the next page - whether you click that number directly or click nextPage).

```
btnClick(event, data){
    const nextPage = data.activePage;
    this.setState({item: nextPage});

}
```